# how to use aliases in graphene-django

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm using python 3.5 with

```
Django==1.11.6
graphene==2.0.dev20170802065539
graphene-django==2.0.dev2017083101
graphql-core==2.0.dev20171009101843
graphql-relay==0.4.5
```

I have a schema that fetch's single objects like this:

```
class Query(graphene.AbstractType):
   story = graphene.Field(storyType, category=graphene.String(), id=graphene.Int())
   def resolve_story(self, info, **kwargs):
        category = kwargs.get('category')
        id = kwargs.get('id')
        if category is not None:
            return models.story.objects.get(category=models.category.objects.get(name=category))
        if id is not None:
            return models.story.objects.get(pk=id)
        return None
```

My problem is that I can't use both `story(category:"category")` and `(id:"id")` in one query. I read [here](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) that I should use aliases but I don't know how.
Thank's for any help.

Comment: Do you want to get one by category and another by pk in the same query or get both using filter?

Comment: @MauricioCortazar The first one: I want to get one by category and another by pk in the same query.

Comment: see my answer and tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is as simple as the example just:

```
{
  storyId: story(id: 1) {
    name
  }
  storyCategory: story(category: "category_name") {
    name
  }
}
```

but you can use `filter` if that is what you mean doing something like:

```
        if category and id is not None:
            return models.story.objects.filter(id=id, category=models.category.objects.get(name=category))
```

and in the query something like:

```
story(id: 1, name: "category_name") {
        name
      }
```